# How do I trim data over 99% in unbalanced panel data in R?

Tags: r, panel, data-cleaning

I have a unbalanced panel data. the simplified example as follows:

```
Firm Year  V1  V2 V3
AAA  2001  0   8   2    
AAA  2002  10  4   2    
BBB  1999  0   8   8    
BBB  2000  7   0   6    
BBB  2001  10  100 1    
BBB  2002  1   5   8    
CCC  2001  2   8   0    
CCC  2002 -98  3  10
```

What I'd like to do is to trim outliers for each year across all frims for each Variable. The way of trim is to assign NA to those values > 99% and < 1% of the data. For example, for year 2000, for Var_1, assign NA to all the values that > 99% or < 1%. Idealy, after trimming the data will look like this:

```
Firm Year  V1  V2 V3
AAA  2001  0   8   2    
AAA  2002  10  4   2    
BBB  1999  0   8   8    
BBB  2000  7   0   6    
BBB  2001  10  NA  1    
BBB  2002  1   5   8    
CCC  2001  2   8   0    
CCC  2002  NA  3   10
```

The real data is massive with lot of unbalanced data structure.

Comment: Your expected output doesn't make sense, what do you mean `values > 99% and < 1% of the data` ? Why isn't the `max` and `min` of each column `NA` then?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear. Let me clarify, for example, in 2002, we have a subset of data of Var_1, (10,1,-98,...) etc. Treat this subset as normally distributed, find the 99% and the 1% of this normal distribution. Trim out the values that above the 99% and below the 1% by assigning NAs. Let's just say the mean and standard deviation of this subset of data is 7 and 22. So -98 is bellow 1% which is -44.18. Does that make sense?

Comment: Then the below answer should work imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following to mark the outliers for each variable for each year at once.

```
data.frame(lapply(df[3:5],                                         # variable indices 3:5
           function(y) ave(y, df$Year, FUN=function(x) 
                             ifelse(x < quantile(x, .01) | x > quantile(x, .99), NA, x)))) 

#   V1 V2 V3
# 1 NA  8 NA
# 2 NA  4 NA
# 3  0  8  8
# 4  7  0  6
# 5 NA NA  1
# 6  1 NA  8
# 7  2  8 NA
# 8 NA NA NA
```

Comment: Hi there, is there a way to keep the "Firm" and "Year" column? Thank you